# Which saves are kept when I enable Steam Cloud synchronization?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

More specifically, if I enable it after I've had it disabled for a while, will it save my offline saves to the cloud or will it pull the cloud data to my computer first?

Also, if I have 2 different save sets on 2 different computers what happens if I enable cloud on both of them one after another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a conflict with the save files, Steam will ask you whether you want to keep the cloud saves or local saves. This will occur with every computer that has greatly different save files.